# Errors in the GIT bash in VSCode

Tags: bash, git, visual-studio-code

I am learning GIT through tutorials and currently and integrated the GIT bash into VSCode. I noticed that when using accents in the comments of the commits, in the installed terminal of GIT there are no problems to show these comments **(image - right side)** but if strange characters appear when I want to see this information through the bash that is integrated into of VSCode **(image - left side)**. Someone could tell me how I can correct this, Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It is not a error!
You have to adjust the character set in VSCode.

Comment: Hi @UtLox, I have verified in the lower right corner of VScode that the configuration is in UTF-8 which is what I have always worked with but there is no change. Could you in what section I should review what you indicate and what is the set of characters that should have. Thank you.

Comment: I don't use VSCode - sorry!